# Timing for numpad Android

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an application on android.  Is there a way to detect if a number on the default numpad is pressed?

For example if I pressed the number 3, I could reference the specific number and have some sort of onclicklistener to execute certain code.  I have looked around but the only solutions to what I need would be to create my own numpad.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there's no such thing as "default numpad"

Comment: I think what I was trying to get at was the numpad that comes up when you click on an EditText field(input type set to "numbers").  Does that clarify it more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override dispatchKeyEvent on the containing activity:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)

Check the keyCode on the event the method is passed to see if it is the 3 key.

Answer (score 0):

I would use setOnClickListener for each number then implements the onClickMethod then use switch inside it to do the calculating process.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button num_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.num_2);
    Button num_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.num_3);
    num_2.setOnClickListener(this);
    num_3.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.num_2:
        $calculate = $current_value + num_2;
        break;
    case R.id.num_3:
        $calculate = $current_value + num_3;            
        break
    }

}
```

}

Comment: In this solution I'd have to create my own buttons with id num_2, num_3, etc right?

Comment: @user2612461 Exactly.